# Filter Results in Jquery on list

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, filter

I downloaded and edited a code that from internet, basically what I want to do is to create a list of strings that I'm reading from the database using JSON.
The list is built perfect, now what I want to do is to filter results (text box) using Jquery.
What's the best way to do that?
Show the full list of results when users type something in a textbox filter those results in the list.

Thanks

```
$(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)
        {
            var list = $("#toggle").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
            for (var i in rows)
            {
            var row = rows[i];
                //var id = row[0];
                var Dname = row[4];
                Dname = Dname.toLowerCase();
                list.append("<li>"+Dname+"</li><div>Pulse</div>");
            }
            $('ul li:odd').addClass('zebra_odd');
            $('ul li:even').addClass('zebra_even');
            $("li").click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You could take a look at [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and [.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works quite nicely:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {                       // Bind keyup event to textbox
    var textboxVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();   // Get value of textbox
    $('ul li').each(function() {                    // loop through the list
        var listVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // get value of the <li>
        if(listVal.indexOf(textboxVal) >= 0) {      // search if textboxVal is in listVal
            $(this).show();                         // if true show this <li>
        } else {
            $(this).hide();                         // else hide this <li>
        }
    });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/PWAXt/